# How do I delay a function for fadeOut?

Tags: jquery, function, methods, fadeout

I have this function:

```
    $('#output').on('click', '[data-action="DELETE_ITEM"]', function () {
            var itemInfo = $(this.dataset)[0];
            var buttonOfProductHTML = document.querySelector(`[data-id='${itemInfo.id}']`);
            var buttonOfDeletion = document.querySelector('[data-action="DELETE_ITEM"]');
            $(buttonOfDeletion.parentElement.parentElement).fadeOut(1000);
            var itemIndex = $('[data-action="DELETE_ITEM"]').index(this);
            cart.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            sessionStorage['shopCart'] = JSON.stringify(cart);
            outputCart();
            handleCartButton(buttonOfProductHTML, 0);
        })
```

I only see the fadeOut effect if I delete the code from cart.splice which removes a row from a table (shopping cart). I guess the deletion way faster than the effect. How can I properly delay the removal of the cart item to see the fadeOut effect?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `fadeOut` method, accept a callback function as second parameter, which is optional. The callback function is executed when the animation gets over. So you can perform `fadeOut` and put all of your code, inside that callback function. :)

```js
$('#output').on('click', '[data-action="DELETE_ITEM"]', function() {
  var itemInfo = $(this.dataset)[0];
  var that = this;
  var buttonOfProductHTML = document.querySelector(`[data-id='${itemInfo.id}']`);
  var buttonOfDeletion = document.querySelector('[data-action="DELETE_ITEM"]');
  $(buttonOfDeletion.parentElement.parentElement).fadeOut(1000, () => {
    var itemIndex = $('[data-action="DELETE_ITEM"]').index(that);
    cart.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    sessionStorage['shopCart'] = JSON.stringify(cart);
    outputCart();
    handleCartButton(buttonOfProductHTML, 0);
  });
})
```

Comment: However, it alters the code. Now, it does not remove the proper item, always the first. Secondly, it redirects the user to the PayPal site. I have a button on this page that does this, but now it automatically does that on deletion. Should I look to another section to correct this or can we do something with the fadeOut? The original code works properly.

Comment: I made a mistake in the code, i.e. the `this` inside the arrow function was referring to the `window` and not to the element. I have corrected that. Now both codes are same :)

Comment: Thanks, it deletes the proper item now. The only thing I don't understand, why the original code does launch PayPal checkout if I press the button, and the fadeOut version launches checkout on the deletion even if I don't want to.

Comment: @DarkArchon I don't think the redirection code is present in the callback function. There might be some triggering code, somewhere else. Could be present inside `outputCart` or `handleCartButton`.

Comment: Yes, I had to remove the static PayPal form from the page, and adding it from JS, too. Thanks!